# Dealing with two least squares problem and an $L1$ Regularization term

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I found this optimization problem in the paper [Signal Processing on Graphs: Causal Modeling of Unstructured Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00173) equation 9:

[image]

where the last term is to ensure that $R_i $ commutes with other $R_j, j \ne i$ such that $[R_i, R_j] = R_iR_j - R_jR_i = 0. $ They say that this is an $\ell_1$ regularization problem. What I struggle with is how to combine the first and last terms into a single least square term. Ideally (which may no be possible) I am looking to have it in a canonical form of $\ell_1$ regularization, where I can plug it into one of the available $\ell_1$ regularization APIs.

Comment: Just throw it in a convex optimization tool, such as CVX, CVXPY, or CVXR, and let it handle that. It will put the problem into whatever standard form is needed by the solver it calls.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I am interested to learn how these frameworks do it although I said in my question is that my end goal is to plug it into an API

Comment: They do the messy algebra you don't want to or know how to do. They can also do far more advanced and exotic transformations into convex "conic" form for problems which are entered according to their rules.

Comment: So we are minimizing only with respect to $R_i$, and the other matrices $R_j$ are held fixed? Should the $\ell_1$-regularization term involve $R_i$ rather than $R_1$?

Comment: Even the first term is ugly to get into OLS form.

Comment: @littleO that is correct.

Comment: @littleO No, $R_j$'s are polynomials of $R_1$, so the sparsity of $R_1$ will ensure the sparsity of other $R_j$'s.

Comment: If we're minimizing only with respect to a specific $R_i$, with the other $R_j$s held fixed, as your notation appears to indicate, then penalizing $\| R_1 \|_1$ has no effect because  $R_1$ is not an optimization variable. If the optimization variable is not simply $R_i$, then you should state very clearly what the optimization variables are in your optimization problem.

Comment: @littleO I see where the confusion is. This is a block coordinate descent algorithm. That is we minimize over $i \in {1,2,\dots,n}$. So we minimize each $R_i$ sequentially starting with $R_1$